# Inserting data into Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been trying for a while inserting data into an Oracle database but, just in some cases, I'm getting the following error:

```
INSERT INTO Estadio VALUES ('Camp Nou', 1957, 99354​)
                                                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00917: missing comma
```

Here's part of my code:

```
INSERT INTO Estadio VALUES ('Camp Nou', 1957, 99354​);
INSERT INTO Estadio VALUES ('Santiago Bernabeu', 1947, 81044​);
INSERT INTO Estadio VALUES ('Wanda Metropolitano', 2017​, 67829​);
INSERT INTO Estadio VALUES ('Benito Villamarin', 1929, 60722​);
INSERT INTO Estadio VALUES ('San Mames', 2013, 53289​);
```

I'm confused because, as far as I know, there should be no problem with commas.
Thanks in advance!

Here's my create database statement:

```
CREATE TABLE Estadio (
nombreEstadio       VARCHAR(60) CONSTRAINT PK_Estadio       PRIMARY KEY,
inauguracion        NUMBER      CONSTRAINT NN_inauguracion  NOT NULL,
capacidad           NUMBER      CONSTRAINT NN_capacidad     NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Can u post your table create statement.

Comment: For sure! There it is

Comment: Do you have semicolon set to be the delimiter?

Comment: There is some special character after some values.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3594/3

Comment: Indeed, there are some special characters. Just rewriting your queries instead of copy-pasting makes it work

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Try the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO Estadio (nombreEstadio, inauguracion, capacidad) VALUES ('Camp Nou', 1957, 99354);
```

It's a best practice to specify the order of the columns for INSERT INTO statement.